# How to create CSS with 2 loops

Tags: html, css

```
<table  class="samplelinktable" >
    <tr>
        <td><a href="samplelink1">samplelink1</a></td>
        <td><a href="samplelink2">samplelink2</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to Create a Css with 2 loops.

```css
.samplelinktable td:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family:arial;
    color:#FFFFF;
    a:hover {
        color: #000000;
    }
}
```

1) When the person hovers through the cell in the table the background of cell becomes blue and the text of the hyperlink which is blue by default to become black

2) When the person hovers over the text of the hyperlink in the cell the black text  automatically must become white.

Please help me out in attaining 2 color changes in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
td{padding:20px;}
.samplelinktable td:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family:arial;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.samplelinktable td:hover > a {
    color: #000000;
}

.samplelinktable td a:hover {
    color: #fff ;
}
```

td padding added for visualization purposes

Answer (score 1):

The only event that matters for the second `a` color is the hover event on the anchor:

```css
.samplelinktable td a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
```

Nested CSS directives are not supported, so remove that style from the td:hover:

```css
.samplelinktable td:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family:arial;
    color:#FFFFF;
}
.samplelinktable td a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
```